# How to apply a method only to a certain sub class of Actor in Stage

Tags: libgdx

My game has a class named `Enemy` which extends `Actor`. Additionally, I have an `EnemyAffector` class which has methods that affect `Enemies`, roughly like this:

```
class EnemyAffector {
    public void affect(Enemy enemy) { ... }
}
```

In my `Stage`, in the `act` method, I want to iterate over all `Enemies` and apply an `EnemyAffector` to them. The obvious way is by casting:

```
@Override
public void act() {
    super.act();
    for (Actor actor: getActors()) {
        if (actor instanceof Enemy) {
            enemyAffector.affect((Enemy)actor);
        }
    }
...
}
```

However, legend has it that using `instanceof` [should be avoided](http://www.javapractices.com/topic/TopicAction.do?Id=31). So, I considered keeping an additional `Array` to which I will add `Enemies` as they are added to the `Stage`, i.e., by overloading my `Stage` with another `addActor` method:

```
public void addActor(EnemyProjectile pEnemyProjectile) { // add to Enemy Array }
```

So now my `act` method looks like this:

```
@Override
public void act() {
    super.act();
    for (Enemy enemy: enemyArray) {
        enemyAffector.affect(enemy);
    }
...
}
```

Yay! No `instanceof`!

However, the problem with this solution is that I will always need to synchronize between the `Enemy` `Array`, and the standard `Actor` `Array` because `Enemies` in the `Enemy` `Array` may have been removed from the `Stage`.

My question is, is there a different, cleaner, approach which can I take here?

Comment: When do you remove the Actors? Can't you remove them from the enemies list at the same time you remove them from the stage actor list?

Comment: Sometimes the easiest solution is the best one. Close your eyes and use instanceof... Less code, less errors...

Comment: @vojta sometimes it can be best. OP would know he should have created a new solution if he ends up not wanting an `instanceof` enemy to be removed from the list (enemies with 2 lives, or cinematic "death talk" reasons?) - or if he ends up wanting to do different things for other Objects as well (*separate `instanceof`'s for "Player", "AlliedNPC", etc*) - Doing it at the start *can* lead to the reason "instanceof" is frowned on (messy code), but if its well thought-out it could be harmless.

Comment: I think in this case `instanceof` is the simplest and therefore best solution.

Comment: The only reason I don't agree is because I find it likely he'll be needing to distinguish between different `Actors` again in the future, and he'll be tempted to make another List at that time, and use another `instanceof` - but he could wait if/until that time comes, so I'm not really against it either. Just don't fall to the "dark side" if you start this way.

Comment: @DoubleDouble as to your first comment: `Actors` remove themselves from the `Stage`: `actor.remove()`. So, in the `Stage` I will need to manually go over all `Actors` to check which are still in the `Stage`.

Comment: @vojta I tend to agree. This seems be one of those cases where `instanceof` cannot be avoided (at least not in an elegant way).

Answer (score 1):

The easiest and in my opinion generating least lines of code is to use **UserObject** Actor field like:

```
    Actor actor = new Actor(); //or its children ofc
    actor.setUserObject("enemy");

    //...

    if( actor.getUserObject().equals("enemy") )
    {
        //yup this is enemy
    }
```

Of course it is not the best solution due to OOP and can be not very flexible in some cases but to be honest in a case like this handling additional arrays etc etc only complicates things.

Notice that **UserObject** is object type so if you want to push there something that Java cannot cast itself you will have to cast it on your own.

---

However if you would want to be **super ok** here's another more elegant solution:

- You are overriding the Actor class with your own **MyActor** class with some **customAction()** method which do nothing. You will be inheriting from this class not from Actor now
- In every child class the method do nothing but in your **Enemy** class you are implementing the funcionality
- In a loop you are casting to (MyActor) and calling customAction method

  ```
  for (Actor actor: getActors()) {
      ((MyActor)actor).customAction();
  }
  ```

  The **customAction** method has a logic from EnemyEffector

This would generate some problems if you are inheriting classes that inherits from Actor (like Label class) and also will be a problem if the EnemyEffector logic is using data that Actor instance should not know because they are global for example and shouldn't be redundant (of course you can also pass the information as a parameter of customAction method)

Comment: Extending a `ActorBase` class is not option for the reasons you mentioned: It prevents me from extending built-in subclasses of `Actor`. The first option is basically `instanceof` with different semantics, as you mentioned too.

Answer (score 1):

You could either use the `UserObject` that you can add to an actor:

```
public enum ActorType
{
    PLAYER, ENEMY, ETC;
}

//...

Enemy enemy = new Enemy();

// Or set this in the constructor
enemy.setUserObject(ActorType.ENEMY);

for (Actor actor : actors)
{
    if (actor.getUserObject() == ActorType.ENEMY)
    {
        // Do stuff...
    }
}
```

Or put your two arrays in an extra class and add methods for adding/removing:

```
public class ActorManager
{
    private Array<Actor>    actors  = new Array<>();
    private Array<Enemy>    enemies = new Array<>();

    public void add(Actor actor)
    {
        actors.add(actor);
    }

    public void add(Enemy enemy)
    {
        actors.add(enemy);
        enemies.add(enemy);
    }

    public void remove(Actor actor)
    {
        actors.removeValue(actor, true);
    }

    public void remove(Enemy enemy)
    {
        actors.removeValue(enemy, true);
        enemies.removeValue(enemy, true);
    }

    // To make sure our backing arrays are not modified:

    public Array<Actor> getAll()
    {
        return new Array<>(actors);
    }

    public Array<Actor> getEnemies()
    {
        return new Array<>(enemies);
    }
}
```

Comment: The first part doesn't really solve the problem it merely switches checking `instanceof` with checking the `UserObject` value. The 2nd part is interesting since it extracts the logic of actor management to a class of its own, however, it's unclear to me how this class would be used within the `Stage` and / or `Actors` context.

Comment: With the first part if you checked for the `UserObject` you can execute `enemyAffector.affect((Enemy) actor);` since you only assign it to enemies, isn't that what you wanted?

Comment: For the second part instead of the field 'actors' you could add a stage (which contains all actors) and wrap the stage methods for a adding/removing, you could even give it a actor factory, so that only this class can create new actors that can be added to your stage. An you can add much more, this is only a small example. For example, I have a 2d array of my entities, so that I can check /get an entity really fast from a click position (no looping, etc). Since all those arrays/collections need to be synchronized all actions concerning entities are handled and distributed by this class.

Answer (score 1):

I quickly encountered a similar situation with `LibGDX` with both the `Actor` and `Stage` class. I created my own sub-class extending `Actor`, which I was going to use as the "base Actor" Object for all my Actors.

That way, you can set up methods which will be called by all your Actors on certain situations.

```
class MyStage extends Stage
{
    public void addActor(MyActor pEnemyProjectile) { // call onAdd }

    //override other methods as necessary,
      //possibly getActors() to return Actors as MyActors, etc
}

class MyActor extends Actor
{

    public void update(double delta)
    {
        //I find it easiest to have "removal" code happen in the Actor's update method, then I can call onRemove()
        //This could happen by finding death conditions or just checking a "isDead" boolean.
    }

    public void onAdd()
    {
        //can set up a default behavior, or just override on other subclasses
    }

    public void onRemove()
    {
        //call for every Actor that gets removed - can extend and remove Enemies from an Enemy list if desired
    }

    //maybe it would be better to check if the Object can be Affected here?
      //rather than keeping and maintaining a separate list
    public boolean isAffected()
    {
        return false; //return true by Enemies
    }
}

class Enemy extends MyActor
{
    //implement onRemove, onAdd, etc..
}
```

If it works better, `MyActor` could also be created as an `interface` instead - and then you could just as easily create sub-classes for `Label` or other `LibGdx` classes which inherit from `Actor`.

I personally chose to make it a sub-class, just because I could create helper-methods which were easier to type and call - such as my "movement" and "rotation" code, which don't use the `Action` classes which `LibGdx` comes with.

Comment: nice solution! :) looking exactly like mine :)

Comment: @m.antkowicz I didn't notice the 2nd part of your answer! Sorry if I've treaded on your toes some

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Please see my comment on @m.antkowicz answer.